# How to Freeze/Thaw ZFS File system to take hardware snapshots

Tags: filesystems, storage, solaris, zfs

Is there any way to freeze/thaw the zfs file system on solaris as any other traditional file system provides this functionality. I needed this to take the hardware (EMC Symmetrix Arrays) snapshots.

I’m aware of the fact that ZFS provides the snapshot/restore functionality but our requirement is to take the hardware snapshots.

Comment: I revised my answer -- I believe this is possible using a feature that's slightly different from what you're requesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@AndrewHenle's response is correct -- today you have to unmount / export the pool to successfully pause new IOs. [`fsfreeze`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-fsfreeze/) is supported by most of the other widely-used filesystems in Linux, so I don't think it's unreasonable to hope that ZFS will support something similar someday. In fact, there is a feature request to support `fsfreeze` in ZFS on Linux [here](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/260), and it doesn't even look that hard to implement (just hard to test ;-)).

That said, most people probably don't *need* to use `fsfreeze` before taking storage-level snapshots, since it's not required for crash consistency -- if your application running on top of ZFS can't deal with a snapshot being taken without freezing the filesystem, it also can't deal with your machine doing an unexpected hard reboot. ZFS is a bit better than other filesystems in this regard because it doesn't need to replay a transaction log or run `fsck` after a hard reboot to ensure correctness. Maybe this performance hit (having to replay the log) is why this is more important on other filesystems.

--- EDIT ----

I remembered a recent feature which could be used to implement something like this, called `zpool checkpoint`. A former colleague implemented this and wrote a brief article about it [here](https://sdimitro.github.io/post/zpool-checkpoint/).

For your use case, the idea is that when you're taking a hardware snapshot:

1. First you would run `zpool checkpoint`, which syncs all in-flight IOs to disk and stores a copy of the pool's uberblock (highest-level block in the filesystem tree) containing all those changes. This is similar to how ZFS snapshots an individual filesystem, but works for the entire pool. This creates a serialization point like the one you would use `fsfreeze` to create, where all IOs started before the checkpoint must finish and all IOs started after it are not captured in the checkpoint.
2. Then you'd take the storage snapshot.
3. When the storage snapshot is done, you'd discard the checkpoint with `zpool checkpoint --discard` on the live system so that ZFS can continue freeing space on disk as it's overwritten (which is not possible while the checkpoint is active since that data may still be referenced by something in the checkpoint).
4. If you restore from the hardware snapshot later, run `zpool import --rewind-to-checkpoint` instead of the normal `zpool import` to roll the pool's state back to the checkpoint, and then discard the checkpoint with `zpool checkpoint --discard` since you don't plan to roll the pool back to that point again once it's running (and you want to be able to free the space consumed by the checkpoint).

This has the added advantage over `fsfreeze` that it does not pause IOs while the checkpoint is taken. However, it also has the disadvantages that (a) it's not used in other filesystems and is therefore a little more complex, and (b) you can't easily synchronize it with other application-level events, since it just happens "sometime" while the CLI command is running.

Comment: Thanks @Dan for the answer. By freezing I mean it should flush all the ongoing IOs to disk to make the file system consistent, block all the write IOs and allow read IOs till the point I thaw the file system. With zpool checkpoint feature how we're ensuring data consistency as it will not block the write IOs while we take the snapshot. Write will be enabled next moment once we done with checkpoint.

Comment: Also zpool checkpoint and for the matter of fact all other methods zpool export, zpool unmount works only pool level. I need something which works with file system level. Also zpool export or unmount commands we're not able to access the pool that's not the case with other file system freeze methods like fsfreeze.

Comment: The key to a consistent snapshot isn’t blocking new writes, it’s making sure that there is a time T where every write which started before T will finish and make it into the snapshot, and all writes starting after T don’t make it into the snapshot. Other filesystems do not do this internally (which is why you have to use fsfreeze), but ZFS does it every few seconds, because it’s part of the way that ZFS can take snapshots. The checkpoint merely allows you to capture the entire pool’s state at time T, and restore to that point later on.

Comment: Also, although the checkpoint is pool-wide, it doesn’t require you to unmount while you do it, so the downsides you’re worried about aren’t applicable. In fact, the disruption will be even less than fsfreeze, because it doesn’t block new writes while it happens (it just makes sure they aren’t recorded in the checkpoint). However, the only way to restore from a checkpoint is during zpool import, which usually happens at boot — that may be why you thought export was necessary to take the checkpoint.

Comment: I'm having little confusion here. How we're making sure that pass T there won't be any write as writes are free to come once we're done with checkpoint which we're taking at time T but snapshot will be T +  and we're taking the snapshot on arrays (hardware snapshot) and not taking the snapshot on checkpoint's data. There will be small window between the time when we take checkpoint and when we take the snapshot for the writes to come which potentially can make the data inconsistent for snapshot.

Comment: That’s why you have to restore the pool to the checkpoint when you restore from the hardware snapshot. (Otherwise you would have captured writes that happened between the checkpoint and the time the hardware snapshot occurred, as you pointed out.)

Comment: We'll restore the pool to the checkpoint by this command - **zpool import --rewind-to-checkpoint** but for this we've to keep the checkpoint and how snapshot is taking part in restoring the pool by this method. Also only one checkpoint can be created for the pool but we want to keep different snapshots. In our case we clone the data from snapshot to some third device and then restore from the third device some time later in future.

Comment: For the first part, as I said in the original answer, you take a checkpoint, take the hardware snapshot, and then discard the checkpoint, so the checkpoint is only present in the snapshot. For the second part, why do you want different sync points for different filesystems? You can only take hardware snapshots across the whole pool / device anyway. (If you really want to do that, you could just sub out `zfs snapshot` for `zpool checkpoint` in my answer -- they both have the same consistency guarantee, `snapshot` is just within a filesystem, and `checkpoint` is across the whole pool.)

Comment: I just want to understand ,how we are dealing with the writes coming between the checkpoint and hardware snapshot. hardware snapshot will have checkpoint + few additional writes which might come after taking the checkpoint and before taking the hardware snapshot. we will backup this hardware snapshot to some protection storage so how we can restore the data (with checkpoint only state) and not the additional writes which come after the checkpoint and before the snapshot.

Comment: When you restore from the hardware snapshot, the first thing you do after boot is rewind the pool to the state stored in the checkpoint. This erases the writes that happened between the checkpoint and the hardware snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

Unmount the filesystem or export the ZFS pool.  And this isn't limited to ZFS.  It applies to most filesystems and volume managers.

Your requirement is fundamentally unsound if you expect to be able to take a snapshot of a live, mounted filesystem or software-managed volume at the hardware device level and have the result be an image of a consistent filesystem.  That falls in the ["I want a pony"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I%20want%20a%20pony) category of requirements.

Comment: A lot of filesystems supportes this, the filesystem waits until all ongoing operations are completed and pauses new operations - this is what LVM also requests from the filesystem when you take a snapshot.

Comment: @nos *A lot of filesystems supportes this,* I'd characterize it as a relatively small number of file systems on a few operating systems support this.  In general I'd say being able to freeze a filesystem isn't an expected feature outside of those limits.

Comment: @nos For example, the ability to freeze isn't listed as a feature on [the Wikipedia "Comparison of file systems" page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Almost all the popular filesystems supports freeze/thaw functionality without un-mounting the file system and only blocks write access during that period. e.g. On Linux - Ext3/4, ReiserFS, JFS, XFS, On Solaris - UFS, veritas file system VxFS, On windows - NTFS, On HP and and aix - UTDM, GPFS, JFS. Most of it provides ioctl api to freeze/thaw the fs. Looking for similar functionality in ZFS as well.

Comment: @Astha You are confusing UFS ([fssnap](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5166/fssnap-1m.html)) and NTFS ([volume shadow copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy)) snapshots with freezing.  Those are pretty much the equivalent of a ZFS snapshot. I wouldn't call ext3/4, JFS, and XFS on Linux and a few HPUX and AIX filesystems "almost all the popular filesystems", especially when Windows is left out.